# Getting data from text file and display it in html canvas

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I'm quite new to php and i need some help to do something. I'm trying to read some datas from a .txt file and then for each row of the document i want to create a canvas that contains that datas.
I managed to pull my datas from the .txt file using this code:

```
<?php
 $file_handle = fopen("sample.txt", "rb");

 while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
 $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
 $parts = explode(' ', $line_of_text);
 echo "";
  }
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

I know that in the echo tag i should display my datas but i don't know how.

This is my script for the canvas:

```
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
// Create gradient
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(10,10,200,0);
grd.addColorStop(0,"#00BFFF");
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0,60,250,70);
ctx.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.strokeText("PASS: ", 80, 110);

ctx.fillText("Name: ", 30, 230);
ctx.fillText("Surname: ", 30, 250);
ctx.fillText("Gender: ", 30, 270);
ctx.fillText("Role: ", 30, 290);
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to get something like this:
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UtH3.jpg)

Comment: First of all, in your code you refer to "context" when the variable name is "ctx". Second, what is your question? Are you trying to figure out how your javascript can receive the file contents from the server? PHP runs on the server; javascript runs on the browser. You would either need to send an AJAX request to retrieve the data from the server or dynamically generate the javascript variables when creating the response. See https://www.wired.com/2010/02/ajax_for_beginners/

Comment: I modified the "context" part. Yes I'm trying to figure out how my javascript can receive the file content from the server.

Comment: please see the link in my previous comment :)

Comment: There is an another way. Put your scripts to your .php file. Open your script tags and fill the gaps with your php code.

Comment: i'm reading it now